# SKProductsrequest return nothing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, skproduct, skpaymenttransaction

I have been google this issue for couple hours. I have attempted something like:

1. confirm Bundle Identifier and product id are absolutely correct
2. remove and reinstall app on both Simulator and real devices
3. I have try both 'productID' and 'com.company.project.productID'
4. The IAP in iTunes connect should be configured correct as well

The only thing I'm not sure is that I haven't fill Banking and Tax things in my iTunes connect. Actually, I just filled the Banking info, but it needs 24 hours to update.

My codes look like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Set IAPS
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "ProductID")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")
    }      
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    println("product request")
    var myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        println("product added")
        println(product.productIdentifier)
        println(product.localizedTitle)
        println(product.localizedDescription)
        println(product.price)

        list.append(product as! SKProduct)
    }
}
```

This code is from a example, it was work very well in my simulator. But when I replace the ProductID with my own productID (of course bundleID as well), the SKProductsrequest become return nothing.

I have no idea why, hope some one can help me. Thx!

Comment: Hi Joey, is the problem has been resolved? Because I have the same issue with your problem..

Answer (score 5):

I was having this issue all week - no matter what I tried code wise and tweaking my build & provisioning settings, I got no products back.

What finally fixed it for me was changing the bundle id for my app xcode from `company.appname` to `com.company.appname`.   Meanwhile you want to refer to your in-app purchase IDs withthe format `com.company.appname.thingforpurchase1` etc.

In trying to solve this, I re-did the process of setting up automatic provisioning within the project and build settings  & I re-added my developer account to xcode again.  After doing this, the above syntax worked for me.   Note that on itunes connect, my apps' bundle ID is still specified as just `company.appname`, but for some reason in xcode it needs the `com.` at the start too.

There is one other thing i've had to do differently with Swift 2.0 vs Swift 1.x - the compiler will no longer accept the product id's are no longer an `NSSet` - instead the request seems to want identifiers be given as a  `Set<String>` - see this in the example below.

Note this solution was developed with and worked in swift 2.0 and xcode 7 beta.

Ex:

```
func requestProductInfo() {
    print("about to fetch product info")
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers:
                Set(productIDs))

            let productIdentifiers: NSSet = NSSet(array: productIDs) // NSset might need to be mutable
            let productRequest : SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)

            //we set our class as its delegate (so we can handle the response)& trigger the request.
            productRequest.delegate = self
            productRequest.start()
            print("Fetching Products");
        }
        else {
            print("can't make purchases")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was US Tax Form and Agreement. Once its approved, everything it will work.

Comment: I believe this is a correct answer for majority of lookers. Thank you!